# Can Vaadin 14 work with the newly-released Jakarta 8 API, specifically Jakarta Servlet?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I see the [Jakarta 8 specifications](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/) have arrived.

Is it possible to use their new release instead of the `javax.servlet-api` artifacts in a Vaadin 14 web app project?

My understanding is that Jakarta 8 is basically a re-packaging of the Java EE 8 API, using the same package names. I understand Jakarta 9 will switch to their own new `jakarta` package names, so that may not work with the current Vaadin 14. But will Jakarta 8 work?

Do I need to do more than replace:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason for why it wouldn't work and I didn't spot any issues based on some quick testing. Vaadin doesn't really do anything special with the Servlet API, so I would be quite surprised if there would be any problems.

Jakarta EE 9 is then a different question. The package names will be changing from `java.*` and `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. I would hope that the server implementations would take care of smoothing over any potential incompatibilities there, but we'll just have to wait and see.